# What causes survivor not to switch from 1 to 0 after Eden GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

What could have caused survivor to use the same space and not switch from 1 to 0 after an Eden GC.

```
Java:  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit, 1.7.0_80
OS: Windows10.
```

settings are given below for test environment in Jboss4.0.4.

```
 JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx12288m -Xms6144m -Xmn4096m -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=1800000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=1800000 -Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver=true
```

[image: VisualVM GC]

Comment: Perhaps, when all remaining survivors happen to be consecutively at the beginning of the survivor space, the copy operation is elided and the spaces not switched. What speaks against such an optimization, is, that it looks such a rare case to me, that I wouldn’t even spend efforts to test for that condition. But only someone knowing the implementation/source code can provide a definite answer.

Comment: Thanks Holger, It dose't seems very rare in my environment as its happening every now and then. May be its something to do with visualVM.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm0aS.png. Any way, like you said may be its not worth digging deeper.

Comment: In principle, it’s possible that a particular gc cycle has no survivors. Note that there’s a reduction of the old gen too at that point, so perhaps something bigger went unused. That would be plausible. Also, not having a switch of the survivor spaces on the next cycle would be in line with my guess about that optimization. After all, if these assumptions hold, it would indicate a close to perfect configured environment for your application, as most objects do not survive the Eden phase. Perhaps, making Eden a little larger would make it even better.